# Is there a file pointer (FILE*) that points to nothing?

Tags: c++, file-pointer

For some reasons I need a file pointer (FILE*) that points to nothing. It means I can pass it to fprintf function and fprintf ignore the file pointer.

for example:

```
void my_function()
{
  FILE* nothing = NULL; // NULL is not correct.
  int n = fprintf(nothing, "PI = %f", 3.14); // Note: When nothing = NULL, error ocured.
}
```

Is there a file pointer (FILE*) that points to nothing?

Comment: Where are you trying to print it to? If by nothing you mean the screen, try `stdout`.

Comment: Because the return value of fprintf is important for me.

Comment: important in what sense? what are you trying to do?

Comment: On some OSes you could try `fopen("/dev/null", "w")` but not a great solution. A better solution would be to use some other way to achieve what your looking for besides the fprintf function.

Comment: I want the length of "PI = %f" after it formatted.

Comment: why not use `sprintf` for that?

Comment: Because `char buffer[How much for any format?]; int n = sprintf(buffer, "PI = %f", 3.14);`

Comment: You know, you can define the format not to take more than X chars etc... Read about the format string, there's an option to specify exactly how much at most `%f` is allowed to take (including how much after the decimal point).

Comment: @littleadv, OP wants to ignore the write, not write it somewhere else.

Comment: Since this is tagged C++, there might be better solutions with C++ libraries. Boost.Format should respect the C format strings: http://codepad.org/xwLTIdJJ

Comment: When you write to this "nothing" file, do you still care for the value of `n`? Or would `0` do for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

Your code will cause a run-time exception. You can use `/dev/null` for example, if you're running on an OS that supports it, but there's nothing like that built-in in C++.

Answer (score 8):

To solve your actual problem (stated in comments), use `snprintf` instead of `printf`, provided that it's available in your C++ implementation (which is not guaranteed in C++03). Pass in a null pointer for the buffer and 0 for the size. Nothing is written, but the return value is the length of the formatted string (excluding nul terminator).

[Edit: oops, I forgot that `snprintf` on Windows doesn't conform to C99. It returns an error if truncation occurs, not the required length. I don't know what they're going to do about the fact that C++0x requires C99-conforming `snprintf`.]

To answer your question, you can fopen `/dev/null` on UNIX-like systems or `nul` on Windows. Writes to the resulting `FILE*` have no effect. However, there is no portable null-device.

Answer (score 0):

why not wrapping the fprintf method call with an `if (NULL != nothing)` statement?

Comment: This should have been a comment, but to answer it: because that wouldn't produce the value `n` requested.

Comment: @MSalters This is indeed an answer. And don't be so picky, it's obvious you set `n=0` in the `else` part.

Comment: @Shabaz: Obviously the length of `PI = %f` is not 0. This suggestion does not even attempt to produce the value requested => not an answer.

Comment: @MSalters: thanks guys - i think my answer is the simplest and straightforward answer (also for code readability)

Answer (score 0):

Although as NirMH said, you can enclose it in `if (nothing != NULL)`, there is another way. You can open a file in read mode (with `"r"`) and when you send it to `fprintf`, the write is ignored (Edit: as discussed in the comments, remember to set `n=0` if it was negative as returned by `fprintf`).

I personally suggest the first method though. The only reason I might do the second is if I can't change the function.

If you don't care if your code is system dependent, you can use `/dev/null` in linux, `nul` in windows etc,

Comment: Is this well-defined behavior? I'm not sure if `fprintf` has to produce the correct result. In particular, can't it return 0 (no characters written) when operating on a read-only file?

Comment: Look at here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html in the return value section it says `If an output error was encountered, these functions shall return a negative value.` Since the operating system doesn't allow writing on files opened in read mode, this operation will fail even if `fprintf` doesn't check it itself. So, yes it is well-defined behavior (maybe not directly defined, but connecting the links you get it). And also, it wouldn't return `0`, it would return a negative value as documented.

Comment: I.e. that confirms that this method doesn't work. A negative value isn't "the length of `PI = %f` after it formatted".

Comment: @Shahbaz what you don't understand that OP wants to know the length of `PI = %f`. 0 is not a valid value for `n`. The whole exercise is being done to obtain the value of n. So that allocation can be made for a real buffer. Eveybody knows enclosing the call in a condition will not call it. That is the not the problem herer.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, you are right. The intent behind the question is as you say. The question directly asks for something else though, and future visitors will stumble upon this question not based on the intent of the asker, but on the actual question.

Comment: That said, the whole question is kind of useless, the information here is all outdated (e.g. windows' `snprintf` _finally_ conforms to C99) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a design mistake.

Obviously, what you want to know is the number of chars needed to write your number.

You are using _*printf_ for that, which is a good idea. You just want to compute the number of chars "written", hence needed. But you don't want anything to be displayed, so you pricked *fprintf* instead of just *printf*. But *fprintf* doesn't work without a FILE to write in...

Like Steve said, you should rather use [snprintf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), which writes into a string in memory.

As steve says, *snprintf* provided with a NULL string should work as intended except on windows. Then on windows, just provide it with an temporary string which you'll discard afterward.

```
size_t computeNumCharsNeededToPrintMyStuff(double d)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    size_t maxBuffSize = 100; // should be plenty enough

    char *tmpBuff = new char[maxBuffSize ];
    ret = snprintf(tmpBuff, maxBuffSize, "PI = %f", d);
    delete[] tmpBuff;

    return ret;
}
```

Then you just call :

```
n = computeNumCharsNeededToPrintMyStuff(3.14)
```

(This func could be enhanced to compute the size needed to display anything but I'd rather keep it simple for now.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fdevnull = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    printf("printf length=%d\n", fprintf(fdevnull, "Hello World '%s'=%f\n", "PI", 3.14159));
    fclose(fdevnull);
    return 0;
}
```