# calling an elaborate function from SIGINT handle - when is it ok?

Tags: c, linux, sigint

I have a large function, and I want to allow the user to stop it and send it to a recovery procedure (implemented by `elaborate_function`). I thought of using a SIGINT handle:

```
void handle(){
    FILE * devNull = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
    elaborate_function(devNull);
}

void foo(){
    signal(SIGINT, handle);
    ...
}
```

The `elaborate_function()` does the following:

1. file manipulation
2. `printf` / `fprintf`
3. calls other functions
4. system calls (`tar, cp, mv...`)
5. reset

I know that using `printf` from a signal handler is considered unsafe ([as said here)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) but from what I understand, the unsafety only means possible bad output, and this doesn't bother me in this specific case (I'll maybe pass `/dev/null` as the `FILE* fout` parameter to block output, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384979/3512538)).

Aside from the `<stdio.h>` functions, is there any other problem with what I intend? This is the simplest way of a non-blocking-input-mechanism I could think of.

*Running only on Linux, so I don't worry about portability*

Answer (score 1):

There are many unsafe function because internally, these function can lock something (like a mutex), so the "worst" scenario for you is that to have a race condition causing a deadlock. You can also have race condition causing sigsev, and many other hellish bug that you want to avoid (since race condition is hard to debug).

As you have said, only the function listed [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) are safe.

For a non-blocking mecanism input :
You can create a thread that will pool the input file.
You can use signal to raise a flag (like "must_read_input") and in your code, call "elaborate_function" as soon as you see the flag raised.
You can modify your "elaborate_function" to use only signal safe function.

There is plenty way.

Comment: How can I figure out if any of my functions uses locks?

Comment: @CIsForCookies It will be hard and mostly useless since the inner mechanism of these function are "implementation-dependant" (I don't know if this is the rigth word). That means that "printf" for Windows will be totally different to "printf" for Debian (one can using mutex for some reason). And worst, there can have difference between Debian8 and Debian9 ...